# What is google's stand on keyword spamming?

Tags: android, google-play, keyword, spam-prevention

I have seen several apps using "keywords" , "tags" at the bottom of application description. obviously such apps rank higher than my app (FYI i am not using keywords/tags) for these keywords in search results. My question is if the keyword stuffing allowed in the description. ?

I would like to see an <strike>official</strike> unofficial response from google here . If keyword spamming not allowed in the market , then what is google doing about these apps , obviously "Report Abuse" doesn't help much.

Also i could not find about this issue anywhere on the "android market for developers help section"

and apparently keyword stuffing is becoming a very common practice in android market

Comment: I've always wondered about this myself, and it is something that I have participated in somewhat. This might need to be a wiki question, though.

Comment: Getting "an official response from google employee here" isn't going to happen. Any "official response" would have to come through their own website or via direct email.

Comment: This is not the place to solicit official responses from Google's employees (or any other company, for that matter). You should be contacting Google directly for clarification on this issue.

Comment: Edited the question above , unofficial responses are welcome too...

Comment: At the very least it will be annoying and create a negative user experience as the entire product description is displayed in the market listing.

Comment: Officially: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2985717